# JAVA - @PostConstruct called everytime browser refreshes. Is it normal?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

There's a method with @PostConstruct that has to be called once when WAS initialized, but it called everytime when I refresh the browser. The method is in a Websocket and I'm using Tomcat, Chrome, Spring and node.js.

```
    @Autowired
    private WebPushDao temp;
    
    private static WebPushDao service;
    
    @PostConstruct     
    private void WebPushDao() {service = temp;}
```

This problem happens only on my computer with same codes, not on my colleagues's computer. I got a new clone of the source and put a new Tomcat but same problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that the class where the code you provide is managed by Spring in a singleton manner

When spring initializes beans, the default is singleton mode, which is only initialized once, but if you do not initialize in singleton mode, it will cause initialization every time you access it.

There are several situations where this result can occur, I will list one first.Refer to the following code：

```
public class Index {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext AcContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfigration.class);

        C1 C1_1 = AcContext.getBean("c1", C1.class);
        C1 C1_2 = AcContext.getBean("c1", C1.class);
        C2 C2_1 = AcContext.getBean("c2", C2.class);
        C2 C2_2 = AcContext.getBean("c2", C2.class);
    }
}

@Configuration
class MyConfigration {
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public C1 c1() {
        return new C1();
    }
    @Bean
    public C2 c2() {
        return new C2();
    }
}

class C1 {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("C1 init");
    }
}

class C2 {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("C2 init");
    }
}
```

When this code is executed, it will output：

```
C2 init
C1 init
C1 init
```

`@Scope("prototype")` makes the bean no longer initialized in singleton mode, that is, every time you try to access the bean, a new object will be reinitialized

So the `init()` method of class `C1` is executed twice

Comment: Code may not be an answer, I guess.. Because there's no other annotations other than ServerEndpoint and PostConstruct in the class file, nothing to initialize spring multiple times. Also, same code works fine on other computer.

Comment: @unyo66 In the two classes C1 and C2, besides `@PostConstruct`, are there any other annotations? Since I can only see limited information, that is, the piece of code you provided and the phenomenon you described, based on these, the reason I can think of is the situation I reproduced in the above code.

Comment: Can you add more details？

Comment: This annotation on the class declaration : `@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws", configurator = HttpSessionConfig.class)` And `@PostConstruct` , `@Autowired` that I added to the text, and some annotations on the methods : `@OnOpen`, `@OnClose`, `@OnMessage`, `@OnError`. It seems to be nothing special contents in the methods, mostly about log.